# Yii dropzone extention (The CSRF token could not be verified)

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload, yii

I want to post Yii csrftoken with dropzone request here is my code

```
   $this->widget('ext.dropzone.EDropzone', array(
            'model' => $model,
            'attribute' => 'file',
            'url' => $this->createUrl('//media/file'),
            'mimeTypes' => array('image/jpeg', 'image/png'),
            'options' => array('sending' => 'function(file, xhr, formData) {
     formData.append("YII_CSRF_TOKEN", "' . Yii::app()->request->csrfToken . '");
                  }',),
        ));
```

//controller > media (it dose not access the controller )

```
    public function actionFile() {
    $save_path = Yii::app()->basePath . '/../media/portfolio/';
    $save_url = Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('//media/portfolio/');

    if (empty($_FILES) === false) {
        $file_name = $_FILES['Company'] ['name']['file'];
        $fileType = $_FILES['Company']['type']['file'];
        $tmp_name = $_FILES['Company']['tmp_name']['file'];
        $file_size = $_FILES['Company']['size']['file'];
        $temp_arr = explode(".", $file_name);
        $file_ext = array_pop($temp_arr);
        $file_ext = trim($file_ext);
        $file_ext = strtolower($file_ext);
        if (!file_exists($save_path))
            mkdir($save_path);
        $new_file_name = rand(0,1000) . '.' . $file_ext;
        $file_path = $save_path . $new_file_name;
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $file_path);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can send it via url as url parameter

Comment: $this->createUrl('//media/file',array('YII_CSRF_TOKEN'=> Yii::app()->request->csrfToken)) it didn't work

Comment: what are you getting in URL for your try?

Comment: http://localhost/tme/ar/media/file?YII_CSRF_TOKEN=3eaf494997afb4bba768dbc6d18380256c403518&

Comment: then you are getting token in url. is it wrong?

Comment: the token generated automatically by Yii, it's still give me (The CSRF token could not be verified.)

Comment: add your controller code in question.

Comment: it dose not access the action at all

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found that worked in my search for getting the CSRF tokens to work with the xupload/blueimp jquery file uploader. Put this in the file "EHttpRequest.php" (or create it) in your components directory.

Source: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/14500-re-writing-a-class-method-without-editing-framework-files/

```
<?php 
class EHttpRequest extends CHttpRequest
{
    public function validateCsrfToken($event)
    {
        if($this->getIsPostRequest())
        {
            $cookies=$this->getCookies();
            if($cookies->contains($this->csrfTokenName) && isset($_POST[$this->csrfTokenName]) || isset($_GET[$this->csrfTokenName] ))
            {
                $tokenFromCookie=$cookies->itemAt($this->csrfTokenName)->value;
                $tokenFrom=!empty($_POST[$this->csrfTokenName]) ? $_POST[$this->csrfTokenName] : $_GET[$this->csrfTokenName];           
                $valid=$tokenFromCookie===$tokenFrom;
            }
            else
                $valid=false;
            if(!$valid)
                throw new CHttpException(400,Yii::t('yii','Lite: The CSRF token could not be verified.'));
        }
    }
}
?>
```

***Caution:** There could be some security risks in doing this, if anyone sees anything wrong with this security-wise, let me know.*

Comment: I tried it but no effect , i created this class in side the component folder and call it from the config 'request' => array('class' => 'EHttpRequest', ...

Comment: Hm well that was definitely the right step to make. I'll look into it more, there may be another code edit I forgot about.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to stop CsrfValidation for some actions

```
//main/config
```

Add the following lines under components

```
       'request' => array(
        'class' => 'HttpRequest',
        'noCsrfValidationRoutes' => array(
            '^site/upload.*$',
        ),
        'enableCookieValidation' => true,
        'enableCsrfValidation' => true,
    ),
```

Then inside the component folder

```
class HttpRequest extends CHttpRequest
{
public $prev_url;

public $noCsrfValidationRoutes = array();


protected function normalizeRequest()
{
    parent::normalizeRequest();

    if(!isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) || $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')
    {
        return;
    }

    $route = Yii::app()->getUrlManager()->parseUrl($this);
    if($this->enableCsrfValidation)
    {
        foreach($this->noCsrfValidationRoutes as $cr)
        {
            if(preg_match('#'.$cr.'#', $route))
            {
                Yii::app()->detachEventHandler('onBeginRequest', array($this,'validateCsrfToken'));
                Yii::trace('Route "'.$route.' passed without CSRF validation');
                break; // found first route and break
            }
        }
    }
}

public function getCurrentUri()
{
    // Get HTTP/HTTPS (the possible values for this vary from server to server)
    $myUrl = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] && !in_array(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']),array('off','no'))) ? 'https' : 'http';
    // Get domain portion
    $myUrl .= '://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    // Get path to script
    $myUrl .= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    // Add path info, if any

    $get = $_GET; // Create a copy of $_GET
    if (count($get)) { // Only add a query string if there's anything left
      $myUrl .= '?'.http_build_query($get);
    }

    return $myUrl;
}
}
```